# IIS Express Web API and multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, iis

-My Web API project running in its own project is fine.

-Trying to run my Web API project from within a solution which contains another web project I get the following suggestion given its 'forbidden'

```
1. Go to the IIS Express install directory.
2. Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
3. Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
```

The first appcmd suggestion works fine, the second does not. I believe the reason is because my site name does not exist in iis Express until it runs or I am doing something else wrong.

This leads to the last question.
-Can I even have a Web API project running while another web project in the same solution consumes its methods. I assume the answer is no.
In fact I assume that if I want to have a web application consume the methods of this Web API application I am going to have to install a proper IIS stand alone.

Comment: I wonder why you ever need to enable directory browsing. If you get 403.14, that is perfectly normal for a Web API project, because it does not have a default page to show by design. Ignore that please.

Comment: another question while I get the above to connect. Isnt a Web API basically a webservice? why am I having a hard time getting information on how to basically add a reference to it in another project? Its like I have to forget literally everything I ever knew about .Net and relearn everything to do the same thing I have done for years...rant over

Comment: What kind of reference do you want to add? Service references are definitely different from assembly/project/package references, as there is a wrapping process. The .NET ecosystem moves fast, so years of experience do not guarantee much if you don't learn new things.

Comment: I wanted to add the Web API project as a reference to the other project. That said i figured it all out, what I want to do can not be done. The Web API project needs to be running in IIS, NOT IIS Express within Visual Studio (that is I know silly but with all the changes in the .Net stack I wanted to ask anyway). So to call the Web API that is running in IIS I just use HttpClient object (from whatever app I am working on which in this case is a mobile app). that I am having an issue with but its a different issue